# How to reduce vehicle speed without "if" statement

Tags: java

I have a vehicle class that gradually increases its speed to 10 and when it reaches 10 it maintains its value (remains 10), and when the speed is reduced, the speed must be reduced gradually. When it reaches 0, it maintains its value (remains 0).

I did not know how to reduce the vehicle speed and maintain the value (0), because the value becomes negative.

I know how to solve the problem through "if", but I want to solve it in a normal way as i did the speed increase to 10.

```
public class vehicle {

    private int speed;

    public void speedUp() {

        speed = (speed + 1) - speed / 10;

    }

    public void slowDown() {



    }

    public void show() {

        System.out.println(speed);

    }

}
```

I tried this but when the value becomes "0" I get an error because a number cannot be divided by 0.

```
public void slowDown() {
        
    speed = (speed - 1) % (speed / -1 );
 
        
}
```

Comment: What's the division for?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to do this without an if statement.  An if statement is likely to be much clearer and not have strange edge cases.

Comment: Since amount of possible options is quite limited you can also create fixed mapping between *current speed* and *next speed*. In case of acceleration which would need to change `0->1, 1->2, ..., 9->10, 10->10` such mapping can be written using `int[]` array like `int[] speedUp = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10};`. Using it acceleration can be done by `speed = speedUp[speed];`. Slowing down can be achieved with array `int[] slowingDown = {0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` which represents mapping `{0->0, 1->0, 2->1, ..., 9->8, 10->9}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases but when `speed` is 0, you want `speed = (speed - 1)`.

When `speed` is zero, you don't want `speed` to change, so you need to add one back. So you need an expression that evaluates to 1 when `speed` is zero and zero when `speed` is between 1 and 10 inclusive. That's `(10 - speed) / 10`.

Putting that together:

```
speed = (speed - 1) + (10 - speed) / 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could return the maximum value between the speed and 0.

`speed = Math.max((speed - 1), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the java ternary operator:

```
speed = speed != 0 ? (speed - 1) % (speed / -1) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the Math.max and Math.min functions.  Math.max(a,b) returns the bigger of a and b.  Math.min(a,b) returns the smaller.  So to make it not go above 10, you want `Math.min(10, speed+1)`.  To keep it at 0, do `Math.max(0, speed - 1)`  This is actually better than the math you have above, as your math will break if there's ever a way to speed up by 2 at once, but Math.min and Math.max will continue to work.